# Extract first word for each row in a column under multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, strsplit, multiple-conditions

I have a dataset contains a column of string. it looks like

`df.a=[['samsung/windows','mobile unknown','chrome/android']]`. 
I am trying to obtain the first word of each row to replace the current string, e.g.[['samsung','mobile','chrome']]

I applied:

```
df.a=df.a.str.split().str.get(0)
```

this gives me the first word but with "/"

```
df.a=[words.split("/")[0] for words in df.a]
```

this only splits the strings that contains "/"

Can I get the expected result using one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `re.findall()` and get only alpha numeric

```
import re
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x : re.findall(r"[\w']+",x)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried: train_id['id_31']=train_id['id_31'].str.replace('/', ' ').str.split(n=1).str.get(0)
. It gets the same result, but yours can apply to other characters too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass regex syntax directly to the split function to split on `/` or `' '` with the pipe character `|`, but his solution only works if those are the *only* delimiters in your data

```
dfa=pd.Series(['samsung/windows','mobile unknown','chrome/android'])

dfa.str.split(r'/| ')

0    [samsung, windows]
1     [mobile, unknown]
2     [chrome, android]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas` function [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) do exactly what you want:

> Extract capture groups in the regex pat as columns in a DataFrame

```
df['a'].str.extract(r"(\w+)", expand=True)
#          0
# 0  samsung
# 1   mobile
# 2   chrome
```